# Raster layer not visible after changing color rendering in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster

I created a new raster and it appears in the layer list, its visible on the screen and the values seems to be correct. 
When I change the "band rendering" from "Singleband gray" to Singleband pseudocolor" the raster seems to disappear from the screen. The values are still there, possible to find by clicking with the "identify features" arrow.

[image: Raster settings]

Comment: Hi @Lark, did you assign any values to a specific colour? If you hit the **Classify** button, it _should_ automatically create a colourmap with the relevant options specified (e.g. min, max values, number of classes etc.).

Comment: Hi! I did use the default settings.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot of the settings you used and would it be possible for you to upload your raster publicly for others to test?

Comment: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/30k3yie/9

Comment: I've edited your question to include your image, easier for others to see :). Now, see the box which has `Value Colour Label`, above that there's a **Plus** sign ( + ), click that and you should see a value and colour show up. Use this to build up your colourmap or click the **Classify** button on the right-hand side to bring up a colourmap automatically. When you're done, click **Apply** then **OK**. It doesn't seem to be visible because no values have been assigned to any colour yet.

Comment: Ha ha ha! Thank you, I probably hit the classify bottom first without notice and then "apply" / "ok". 
Again, thank you!

Comment: Most welcome buddy, glad you got it working :)